# Can the alternative hypothesis depend on the sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

Suppose that we want to test:

$$H_0: \theta = 0 \,\,\, vs. \,\,\, H_1:\theta = 1/n,$$

where $n$ is the sample size used to test the hypothesis, and the sample used for this is $X_i \sim f(;\theta)$. Is it valid to state an alternative hypothesis which is sample size dependent?

Comment: a well known problem in science is that the likelihood of getting extreme value is higher for low n. In that case, if you were testing a hypothesis then you expect the effect size to be  dependent on n. However, you would not test the hypothesis that effect size is dependent on n in this way, rather you would evaluate effect size vs n on the null that they are unrelated with the alternative that they are. My intuition is that the scenario in your question is better reframed in a similar way, otherwise you have a single point not a testable distribution.

Answer (score 3):

No. Why would the value of $\theta$ - a parameter of the distribution of the population depend on the number of observations in the sample that you draw from the population? Only the power of the test depends on the sample size but the parameter was determined before you drew your sample.

Comment: Do you have any reference for your claim (I could accept that as an answer)? Basically you answered with a No, and my own question :D.

Comment: She didn't actually answer with your own question, but instead made the point that the parameter is determined *before* you draw your sample, and therefore, by implication, cannot be a function of the sample size.  Your question was about validity, hers was rhetorical.

Comment: @jbowman Any reference to justify that claim? :)

Comment: How can the parameter used to draw the first observation "know" how many observations you intend to draw?

Comment: @jbowman Maybe it is a very smart parameter. I see your point, I was just hoping that I would get a good reference to justify that the value of the parameter in the alternative should be independent from the sample size, but I see that ain't gonna happen.

Comment: Why do you need a reference?  (This is a serious question, not snark...)

Comment: @jb I, for one, am sceptical.  See the alternative answer offered by Noah, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It's rare for the alternative hypothesis to take on a single value. Typically it represents a range of values, often the complement of the set of values listed for the null hypothesis.

That said, it is possible for a hypothesis to be about a parameter that describes a sample when that sample is the population. I'll provide a toy example for which your hypotheses directly apply, but in the research I do, sample or individual parameters appear in (at least) two places:

1. Estimating the sample average treatment effect in causal inference. The potential outcomes are missing for individuals, and the value of the missing potential outcome for each individual is a parameter. The mean of the potential outcomes under treatment and under control are also parameters. These values do not describe a population but rather just the sample. They are still parameters and they are still estimated.
2. Estimating scale scores in factor analysis. Each individual has a value for a latent variable that is unobserved. We are interested in estimating those values for those individuals. For each individual, we assume the factor score is drawn from some distribution, but the parameter of interest refers to the value for an individual.

For your example, consider the following. You have a population of $n$ units, which is also your sample. You are interested in the value of a latent variable $\theta$, which is the same for each individual, and represents the proportion of a cake eaten by that individual. If no cake is eaten, $H_0: \theta = 0$. If any cake is eaten, $H_1: \theta = 1/n$, because everyone eats the same amount of cake. To estimate $\theta$, you ask each individual whether they are hungry or not. The proportion of hungry people is the test statistic for your test. If that proportion is greater than .5, we fail to reject the null hypothesis. Otherwise we reject the null hypothesis.

Hopefully it's clear that this example concerns the testing of a hypothesis about the unknown value of a parameter, and hopefully it's clear that under the alternate hypothesis the value of the parameter depends on $n$. This is of course an unrealistic toy example, but my understanding is that there is nothing preventing a hypothesis from being written as you have written it. You would likely never find such a hypothesis in an applied research question (mostly for the reason I mentioned in my first paragraph), but it is logically possible.

Comment: It seems to me that the $n$ is not necessarily your sample size; you could sample any number of people out of the population regardless of $n$.  The parameter $\theta$ depends on the population size, not the number of people you ask.

Comment: OP's question doesn't make much sense because you never supply a single value for the alternate hypothesis. If only two values are in the domain of the parameter, then it doesn't matter how they are chosen; {0,1}, {1,2}, {0, 1000} all work and will all yield the same conclusion. The fact that we're dividing by $n$ is indeed arbitrary. But I provided a logically plausible scenario in which the value of the parameter under the alternative hypothesis is a function of the sample size. Here, the population size necessarily equals the sample size because our inference is only about the sample.

Comment: I'm probably missing something important, but I don't see why the sample size *has* to equal the population size in your example.  You can sample $n-1$ or even just $1$ of the $n$ individuals in the population.  If you ask $3$ people if they are hungry, $\theta \neq 1/3$.  You are defining the sample to be the population, but for purposes of calculating your test statistic, it never is, it's the people you ask, and in your example it just so happens that you ask $n$ people - but you don't have to.

Comment: It's because the sample are the only units under study. My point was to explain that parameters can refer to a sample. If you require that a parameter refers only to a population, then the sample must be the same as the population for my example to hold water. In my example, only those in the sample had the opportunity to eat cake. If you only used a subset of the sample to compute the test statistic, you could indeed still perform a test on the same parameter. My example was simply demonstrating that it's *possible* to have an alternate hypothesis with $n$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

I read the previous answer and comments but still I think there is something else there. I consider a sampling distribution. A sampling distribution has n, the number of samples as parameter. It is a statistic and if we want to draw inferences about the sampling distribution itself, and not about an eventual distribution which it approximates, by virtue of central limit theorem or whatever, I see a case for you hypothetical situation. Consider for example Kolmogorov–Smirnov test where we use a sampling distribution. I think of course that using samples to draw inference on populations is not possible, and I agree to comments

Comment: The sampling distribution is determined as soon as you pick the number of samples (call it k) to draw from the population. Would you then want to draw n-many samples from the sampling distribution? If so, the parameters of the sampling distribution are already fixed.

Comment: @rapaio using samples to draw inferences about populations is all frequentist statistics does.

Comment: Grada Classical statistical techniques support decision making, which goes far beyond drawing inferences about populations.